# Order implicit groups

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given this set...

```
Site, Date
4   10/10/18
3   10/10/18
4   07/10/18
5   12/10/18
3   11/10/18
5   13/11/18
```

I want to order it such that the rows are ordered by site and the site groups are ordered by MIN date.

i.e.

```
Site, Date
4   07/10/18
4   10/10/18
3   10/10/18
3   11/10/18
5   12/10/18
5   13/11/18
```

I have tried using...

```
SELECT

    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Site ORDER BY (Date)) AS GroupRank,
    a.*
FROM

    (select * from
    (select 4 AS Site,   '10/10/18' as date union
    select 3,   '10/10/18' union
    select 4,   '07/10/18'  union
    select 5,   '12/10/18'  union
    select 3,   '11/10/18'  union
    select 5,   '13/11/18'  as date ) b) a
    order by GroupRank
```

The results don't make sense.

```
1   3   10/10/18
1   4   07/10/18
1   5   12/10/18
2   5   13/11/18
2   4   10/10/18
2   3   11/10/18
```

It's supposed to be partitioning by site but it's given the same rank to rows with different sites.

Comment: A site with a greater value may have a lower date than a site with a lower value and the query needs to order the site groups by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't figure out how to do this using OVER clause. This joins the rows to a subquery that derives the order.

```
SELECT
    a0.Site,
    a0.Date
FROM
    (SELECT 4 AS Site, '10/10/18' AS Date UNION
    SELECT 3,   '10/10/18' UNION
    SELECT 4,   '07/10/18' UNION
    SELECT 5,   '12/10/18' UNION
    SELECT 3,   '11/10/18' UNION
    SELECT 5,   '13/11/18') a0
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(date)) as RowNumber,
        Site
    FROM
        (SELECT 4 AS Site, '10/10/18' AS Date UNION
        SELECT 3,   '10/10/18' UNION
        SELECT 4,   '07/10/18' UNION
        SELECT 5,   '12/10/18' UNION
        SELECT 3,   '11/10/18' UNION
        SELECT 5,   '13/11/18') a1
    GROUP BY
        Site) b
ON
    a0.site = b.site
ORDER BY
    RowNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT

    min(date) OVER (PARTITION BY Site) AS MinDate,
    a.*
FROM

    (select * from
    (select 4 AS Site,   '10/10/18' as date union
    select 3,   '10/10/18' union
    select 4,   '07/10/18'  union
    select 5,   '12/10/18'  union
    select 3,   '11/10/18'  union
    select 5,   '13/11/18'  as date ) b) a
    order by MinDate, Site
```

Answer (score 1):

That is another case of `max-by-group` problem.

```
SELECT w.Site
     , w.Date
  FROM table AS w
  JOIN ( SELECT Site -- fetch MIN Date for each Site, sort them and enumerate
              , MIN(Date) AS mindate
              , IF(@cnt = '', 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS cnt
           FROM table
          GROUP BY Site
          ORDER BY mindate ASC
       ) AS z ON z.Site = w.Site
 ORDER BY z.cnt ASC   -- Now order the result by numeration of MINs
        , w.Date ASC  -- Then by Date inside that groups
;
```